# Remove or Expire OAuth Token Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, token

I am using below code to generate `OAuth` token. It is working fine. Now, I want to remove/ expire the token whenever I logout from the system. How can I achieve this?

```
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);
context.Validated(ticket);
context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
```

I tried `Authentication SignOut` method but it is doing nothing. Do I need to use both `OAuthDefaults` and `CookieAuthenticationDefaults` to generate the token?

Comment: Is this asp.net core?

Comment: @BinaryPatrick no. It is `MVC`.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth tokens are usually self-contained (JWT) which means it contains user information and also expiry time of token, therefore you can not remove or expire existing tokens.

Comment: Then, if someone has token then even after logout, it can be misused.

Comment: Yes that's the nature of it. Even cookies are like that, if you store cookie somewhere, then logout and then add cookie to browser yourself you are still authenticated

Comment: Is there anyway here to prevent this issue?

Comment: you can use Reference Access Token. check this link for more information http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/reference_tokens.html

Comment: You can store a list of tokens you've expired also.